# jQuery $.get() isn't being called on button click

Tags: jquery

I've got a button that when pressed calls the jQuery $.get() and it's supposed to return a value and put in in an input field (text box) but it never gets called. What am I doing wrong?..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button#getbasedomain').click(function() { 
         var contentSource = $.trim($('input#contentsource').val());
         if (contentSource == '') {
            alert('No Content Source entered.');
            return false; // THIS GETS CALLED, WORKS FINE WHEN SOURCE IS EMPTY
         } else {
             $.get('admin/getbasedomain.php?id=' + contentSource, function(result) {
                 $('input#basedomain').val(result);
                 alert('$.get was run. Result = ' + result ); // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED.
             });
             return false;
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Quick check: Are you running from a server? What happens in the console? What does the browser say in the address bar?

Comment: Is the else case even executed?

Comment: Running from my laptop (development). When I click the button, nothing happens, no postback, but not alert either.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, the else case is being executed.

Comment: @user4496950 What do you see in the console?

Comment: Is **result** a string or what? can you just try to alert a text, without variables and tell me what's up?

Comment: The console is throwing back a 404 and now I'm trying to figure out why..

Comment: @user4496950 Ha ha... Now you got that!!! `:D` It never executes the success function if it is 404.

Comment: I swear it's always something so trivial.. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect a response 404 or 50x `:)`. Try adding a `.fail()` chain to the get request. I expect something wrong in your php script, or it just can't find the php script.

```
$.get('admin/getbasedomain.php?id=' + contentSource, function(result) {
    $('input#basedomain').val(result);
    alert('$.get was run. Result = ' + result ); // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED.

}).fail(function(e){
      alert("OH NO something went wrong.. what could it be...");
});
```

Check the network tab in your browser console to see if the request gets fired and what the response code is